# numpy get slices of array between start and end indices

Tags: numpy

If I have an array `x`, an array of start indices `s`, and a distance `d`, how do I create an array `y`, s.t. `y[i] == x[s[i]:s[i]+d]`?

Comment: @zipzit Not homework, actual work lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation     `y= x[s:s+d].copy()` .   ewwww.. not quite sure this is what you want.  How many i values are there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe but can't find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a strided view of a sliding `d`-window into `x` and then use advanced indexing:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (20,))
>>> d = 4
>>> s = np.random.randint(0, 17, (10,))
>>> 
>>> x
array([2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 8, 2, 6, 6, 0, 2, 8, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 9, 8])
>>> s
array([16,  4,  6,  0, 16,  1, 14,  4,  6,  6])
>>> 
>>> assert x.ndim == 1
>>> assert x.flags.contiguous
>>>
>>> xx  = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (x.size-d+1, d), 2*x.strides)
>>> y = xx[s]
>>> y
array([[6, 2, 9, 8],
       [6, 4, 8, 2],
       [8, 2, 6, 6],
       [2, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 2, 9, 8],
       [4, 5, 6, 6],
       [5, 1, 6, 2],
       [6, 4, 8, 2],
       [8, 2, 6, 6],
       [8, 2, 6, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can use tuple indexing:

```
x[np.stack((s,s+d))]
```